# With Django, how to display User friendly names in the template using grouper?

Tags: python, django, templates

My model offers a choice list:

```
class Interview(models.Model):
    class InterviewStatus(models.Model):
        PENDING = '1-PDG' 
        XED = '0-XED'
        DONE = '2-DON'
        COMPLETE = '3-COM'
        ITW_STATUS = [
            (PENDING, "Interview Planned"),
            (XED, "Interview Cancelled"),
            (DONE, "Interview Done"),
            (COMPLETE, "Interview Done and Assessed")
        ]
```

which is implemented in the model fields:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                            blank=False,
                            null=False,
                            default=InterviewStatus.PENDING,
                            choices=InterviewStatus.ITW_STATUS,
                            verbose_name="Statut de l'interview")
```

When creating a new object, everything is OK.
My template is written as such :

```
{% regroup object_list by status as status_list %}
    <h1 id="topic-list">Interview List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for status in status_list %}
        <li><h2>{{ status.grouper }}</h2></li>
            <ul>
                {% for interview in status.list %}
                    <li><a href="{{ interview.get_absolute_url }}">{{ interview.official }}{{ interview.date_effective }} </a></li>
        {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

What I get as an outcome in my browser is:

**. 1-PDG**

- item1
- item2

etc.

My Question is:
How could I obtain the User friendly names instead of the values, which are supposed to be displayed exclusively in the html field:

```
<option value="1-PDG" selected>Interview Planned</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group.list` is just a python `list` and in templates you can index by using `variable.<index>` so you can get the first object in the list and use it's [`get_FOO_display` method [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) to display the human friendly name:

```
{% regroup object_list by status as status_list %}
    <h1 id="topic-list">Interview List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for status in status_list %}
            <!-- Use `status.list.0.get_status_display` here -->
            <li><h2>{{ status.list.0.get_status_display }}</h2></li>
            <ul>
                {% for interview in status.list %}
                    <li><a href="{{ interview.get_absolute_url }}">{{ interview.official }}{{ interview.date_effective }} </a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and instantly !

Answer (score 1):

To display the user friendly names you have given instead of the values.

```
<option value="1-PDG" selected>{{ interview.get_status_display }}</option>
```

**{{ instance.get_field_display }}**

In your case instance is **interview**, field is **status**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it decreases the level of automation, compared with the solution proposed by Abdul Aziz Barkat.